# Get all child nodes javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to add a html with a SPACE after in a contenteditable div;
The problem is that, with above code it only return the content of the first DIV and ignore everything else.

```
var tdiv = document.createElement('div');
tdiv.innerHTML = '<div>testing html</div>&nbsp;';
var replacment = tdiv.firstChild; // 

el.insertNode(replacment); // it is just the purpose, "el" is the HTML element
```

With this the nbsp will be removed.

Comment: What is the link between the title and the content of the question ?

Comment: *"With this the nbsp will be removed."* No, it won't.

Comment: What are you asking here?? How to get all child nodes? No ... so what else?

Comment: This question is really not clear.  It appears that there are at least 4 different things that it might mean, but I'm guessing that it's actually none of those 4 and something else.

Comment: With no clarification from the OP, this question should be closed as "Unclear What You're Asking".

Comment: I am sorry, I am fixing the question. My english is not the best one. I am trying to add an HTML with a space after in a contenteditable div, but it removes the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all children of `tdiv` to be added to `el` then try

```
var el = document.getElementById('x')
while (tdiv.firstChild) {
    el.appendChild(tdiv.firstChild);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xezs92v7/)

Comment: @devnull69 did you even check the attached fiddle :)

Comment: this is a close answer. I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: I'd like to remove the downvote, but I can't. The code is in fact working correctly because it removes the `firstChild` from `tdiv `upon appending it to `el`. I didn't expect that :-)

Comment: Thank you @ArunPJohny . With your answer I resolved like this:

 tdiv = document.createElement('div');
                                tdiv.innerHTML = replacment;
                                replacment=document.createDocumentFragment();
                                while(i=tdiv.firstChild) replacment.appendChild(i);
                                startAfter = replacment.lastChild;

Answer (score 1):

You can create an element with an nbsp in it like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
```

If you really just want an element with a space of text, you can just create a text node:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
```

---

Looking at your question again, it is actually quite unclear what you're really asking and it appears that there are many different things your question might mean.  So, this is just one possibility for what you might be asking.

---

If you want to add it as an element, then you need to put it in some sort of container since a non-breakingspace isn't an element by itself.  You can wrap it in a `<span>` element like this and then insert the `<span>`.

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
el.appendChild(span);
```

---

Or, maybe it works just fine to insert a text node with a space in it:

```
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry for my bad english. I need it as an object to add as object.insertNode(replacement); It will added to a contenteditable div

Comment: @JohnMark - I added some more options.  It still isn't entirely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank for your help. I ll need to return it in a selection range like: .range.insertNode(replacment);
.range.setStartAfter(replacment);

Thats why I cant use the appendChild and this is my difficulty.

Comment: @JohnMark - You probably ought to just start over with a new question where you describe the ACTUAL problem you're trying to solve.  Include the contenteditablediv, a detailed description of exactly what result you're trying to achieve and what you're trying to do with a range (which I still don't understand).  I'm signing off for the evening so can't help any further tonight.

Answer (score 0):

After Arun P Johny Idea I resolved like this:

```
var replacement = '<div>testing</div>&nbsp;',startAfter,i,tdiv = document.createElement('div');
tdiv.innerHTML = replacment;
replacment=document.createDocumentFragment();
while(i=tdiv.firstChild) replacment.appendChild(i);
startAfter = replacment.lastChild;

 // This is my extra code to the contenteditable div insert and positioning the caret - this.range is my selection range.
 this.range.insertNode(replacment);
 this.range.setStartAfter(startAfter);
```

Thank you all, even for the down votes :P